# Named pipes linux

Tags: c++, qt, named-pipes

I made 2 threads, one has to read the other has to write.
But i get undefined behaviour, sometimes i can read 1 line, sometimes 1000. It does not make alot of sense to me.

What i do is the following:
1. i create a fifo with mkfifo() in main.cpp
2. i start 2 threads, one that reads, the other writes. reader.cpp, writer.cpp

In those threads, every loop i open the fifo and i close it, because it wont work if i only do that once outside the loop, which i find also strange.

I have been looking for good examples but i found none.

My questions is simple, how can i make the fifo (Reader) wait for incoming data and read it when it is available. It should be able to run at 4Mhz.

I hope that somebody can help me out because this is the 3rd day i am breaking my head on this. If it matters im using Qt 4.8.

EDIT: I found the solution to my problem:

main.cpp

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include "reader.h"
#include "writer.h"
#include <sys/types.h>  // mkfifo
#include <sys/stat.h>   // mkfifo
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    int fifo = mkfifo("/tmp/fifo", S_IWUSR | S_IRUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH);

    Reader r;
    Writer w;
    r.start();
    w.start();

    return a.exec();
}
```

writer.h

```
#ifndef WRITER_H
#define WRITER_H

#include <QThread>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

class Writer : public QThread {

    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Writer(QObject *parent = 0);

private:
    void run();

};

#endif // WRITER_H
```

reader.h

```
#ifndef READER_H
#define READER_H

#include <QThread>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

class Reader : public QThread {

    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Reader(QObject *parent = 0);

private:
    void run();

};

#endif // READER_H
```

writer.cpp

```
#include "writer.h"

char * phrase = "Stuff this in your pipe and smoke it\n";

using namespace std;

Writer::Writer(QObject *parent) : QThread(parent) {}

void Writer::run() {

    int num, fifo;
    if ((fifo = open("/tmp/fifo", O_WRONLY)) < 0) {
       printf("%s\n", strerror(errno));
       return;
    }
    while (true) {

        if ((num= write(fifo, phrase, strlen(phrase)+1)) < 0) {
            printf("ERROR: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        }
    }
    close(fifo);

}
```

reader.cpp

```
#include "reader.h"

using namespace std;

Reader::Reader(QObject *parent) : QThread(parent) {}

void Reader::run() {

    int num, fifo;
    char temp[38];
    if ((fifo = open("/tmp/fifo", O_RDONLY)) < 0) {
        printf("%s\n", strerror(errno));
        return;
    }
    while (true) {
        if ((num = read(fifo, temp, sizeof(temp))) < 0) {
            printf("%s\n", strerror(errno));
        }
        printf("In FIFO is %d %s \n", num, temp);
    }
    close(fifo);
}
```

Comment: People do that to you for the craziest reasons. Happens to everyone. I wouldn't worry about it and would start to get used to it. It's sad, I know. Upvoted, found this actually useful.

Comment: @Eduard Luca Your reaction is much appreciated and im glad you found it usefull. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic read() and write() functions make no promise to read or write all available data.

You need something like:

```
int tot = 0;
while (tot < sizeof(temp))
{
    num = read(fifo, temp + tot, sizeof(temp) - tot);
    if (num < 0)
        break;
    tot += num;
}
```

And the same for write.

Comment: if i understand this correctly it will read until nothing is left to read. However this process has to continue until it is shut down manually. Basically data may come at any time and it the fifo does not always have data.

Comment: I should perhaps clarify that my answer is an answer to why you get undefined behavior. read() and write() will always read or write at least one byte if there is one available/place for one.

Comment: This is what i dont understand, normally a fifo should be able to receive all data and buffer it until it is read. Even if it is empty the process should be able wait until data arrives.

Comment: The fifo does all this, just as you describe. It's just that read() doesn't guarantee to return all available data when you call it. So if the fifo contains 12 bytes of data read(fifo, buffer, 100) will return any value between 1 and 12 and that is correct. You will get all of the 12 bytes if you call read() over and over again (or you might get it all in the first call).

Comment: write() works exactly the same, if you wish to write 12 bytes it might write between 1 and 12 bytes and that is also correct. If you need to know if a read() or write() will block or data directly you should use select().

Comment: So i.o.w pipes are not really a good alternative to pass on data. To print a string somewhere it seems to be all ok but once you have a certain amount of data you have to do magic tricks to get it all done it seems. My solution is to make a class with a read and write and simulate a fifo with a list and a mutex. That works alot better and i have alot less code.

Comment: I agree that pipes (especially named pipes) are more useful for interprocess or subprocess communication than thread communication. But when you know the size of the data to be transfered, looping around read() and write() is simple enough.

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem when periodically opened and closed a single pipe. Re-creation of pipe (in reader process, when EOF is met) will be a solution.